# How to make font size bigger in tablet PC?

Tags: android, tablet

```
tv.setTextSize(14);
```

I set TextView font size to 14sp.
When I run my app in Nexus One, font size is ok.
But, when I run it in Nexus 7, font size is so small.
This is because Android scales font size according to density.
Nexus 7 density is lower than Nexus One, Android scaled font size down.
How can I adjust font size proportional to screen size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an XML resource. In an XML resource file (I usually call mine 'dimens.xml'), define a dimension resource called something like `font_size`. Create a 'dimens.xml' file in the folders 'values-normal' and 'values-large'. The font size in 'values' will be used by default, but a large screen (like the Nexus 7) will use the size in 'values-large'. You could also define it in 'values-xlarge' if you wanted to explicitly support 10" tablets.

Settings the size can be done in XML with `textSize="@dimen/font_size"` and from code with `tv.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size))`.

Your dimens.xml file should look like this:

```
<resources>
   <dimen name="font_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will be better if you use the dimens.xml approach, and generate different versions for phone and tablet in folder:

res/values/dimens.xml -> For default sizes

res/values-normal/dimens.xml -> For phone sizes

res/values-large/dimens.xml -> For tablet sizes (mind setting bigger values for font-size, may paddings, and so on...

Comment: the 'values' folder isn't for phones. it's for EVERYTHING that doesn't have a qualified version. that's why you should use 'values-normal' if you have phone specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it from your `dimes.xml`

Define a dimension in the `dimens.xml`. Eg:

```
<dimen name="my_text_size">14sp</dimen>
```

And then use that in your code:

```
tv.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_text_size));
```